# Optimize multiple queries into one

Tags: sql

I would like to optimize this SQL query. I'm having trouble doing more than one query at a time. Any suggestions would be great.

```
SELECT TeamID, JerseyNumber, COUNT(FrameNumber) AS T
INTO Temp2
FROM PlayerTrack
GROUP BY JerseyNumber, TeamID

SELECT TeamID, JerseyNumber, COUNT(FrameNumber) AS NI
INTO Temp3
FROM PlayerTrack
WHERE Interpolated = 0
GROUP BY JerseyNumber, TeamID

SELECT TeamID, JerseyNumber, COUNT(FrameNumber) AS I
INTO Temp4
FROM PlayerTrack
WHERE Interpolated = 1
GROUP BY JerseyNumber, TeamID

SELECT Temp2.TeamID, Temp2.JerseyNumber, Temp2.T, Temp3.NI, Temp4.I 
INTO Temp5
FROM Temp2
INNER JOIN Temp3 ON Temp2.TeamID = Temp3.TeamID 
                 AND Temp2.JerseyNumber = Temp3.JerseyNumber
INNER JOIN Temp4 ON Temp2.TeamID = Temp4.TeamID 
                 AND Temp2.JerseyNumber = Temp4.JerseyNumber

SELECT TeamID, JerseyNumber, (NI *1.0 /T) * 100 AS NIPercentage, (I *1.0 /T) * 100 AS IPercentage
FROM Temp5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT jt.*,
       (NI *1.0 / T) * 100 as NIPercentage,
       (I *1.0 /T) * 100 as IPercentage
FROM (SELECT TeamID, JerseyNumber, COUNT(*) as T,
             SUM(CASE WHEN Interpolated = 0 THEN 1 END) as NI,
             SUM(CASE WHEN Interpolated = 1 THEN 1 END) as I
      FROM PlayerTrack
      GROUP BY JerseyNumber, TeamID
     ) jt
```

You don't need temporary tables.

Or more simply:

```
SELECT TeamID, JerseyNumber, COUNT(*) as T,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Interpolated = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NI,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Interpolated = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as I,
       AVG(CASE WHEN Interpolated = 0 THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END) as NI_percentage
       AVG(CASE WHEN Interpolated = 1 THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END) as I_percentage
FROM PlayerTrack
GROUP BY JerseyNumber, TeamID;
```